# JavaScript onmouseover not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, mouseevent

I've got this HTML:

```
<div onmouseover="seth1();">
    <a onclick="showh1();">h1</a>
    <a onclick="showh2();">h2</a>
</div>

<div id="h1" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="h2" style="display: none;"></div>
```

and this Javascript to display automatically `h1` after 4 seconds or display one of both when users clicks:

```
var settime;
function seth1() {
    settime = setTimeout('showh1();', 4000);
}
function showh1() {
    clearTimeout(settime);
    document.getElementById('h1').style.display = "block";
}
function showh2() {
    clearTimeout(settime);
    document.getElementById('h2').style.display = "block";
}
```

But when I click to show `h2` it also shows `h1`, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example works just fine, but stuff happens that you probably didn't expect.

`onmouseover` gets triggered more than once if you aim too slow with your mouse cursor. If you can manage to set your mouse cursor onto your `h2` link really fast, then `onmouseover` will only be triggered once and your `h1` div will not show up.

If you move your mouse cursor too slow, `seth1()` will be called multiple times, therefore assigning multiple values to `settime`. If `settime` is overwritten, the first (few) call(s) cannot be canceled anymore, since their ID is gone.

In your `showh2()` method you access the current value of settime, so probably only the last call of `seth1()` will be canceled. All others continue, so your `h1` DIV will be displayed four seconds after you hovered your first DIV for the first time.

Test it yourself, check the console logs: https://jsfiddle.net/krbbyzaq/2/

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in order to click in the element `<a onclick="showh2();">h2</a>`, you necessarily need to trigger the mouseover event in the wrapper div. If you don't want to trigger the mouseover while clicking on that element you should apply the event listener to that same element and remove it from the wrapper div. You should also try and explore the `onmouseenter` event. It could suit your particular needs better.

Check this example to see if this is what you're looking for -> https://jsfiddle.net/krbbyzaq/4/

Comment: I can produce weird results in your jsfiddle, too. Just enter h1 a few times, then click h2. H1 shows up anyway. Guess his main intent was to cancel a timeOut.

Comment: so clicking in '<a onclick="showh2();">h2</a>' should cancel the h1 timeout?

Comment: I don't want to come of harsh, but... you copied my JSFiddle and didn't read my answer? If you start multiple timeouts you have to cancel multiple timeouts.

Comment: you're not being harsh and it's not "your" JSFiddle. I copied the fiddle you prepared and changed it, and you're right ... I didn't read your answer. Is that offensive? I read the question and interpreted that this was what the OP wanted. I guess I was wrong. I've edited my answer ... I think this is what was intended. Just change onmouseover to onmouseenter.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you two for your help. Now I understand better my problem.
I finally solved by this:

HTML

```
<div id="setter" onmouseover="seth1();" style="height: 10px; width: 100%;">
<div>
    <a onclick="showh1();">h1</a>
    <a onclick="showh2();">h2</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var settime;
function seth1() {
    settime = setTimeOut('showh1();', 4000)
    document.getElementById('setter').style.width = "0px";
}
function showh1() {
    clearTimeout(settime);
    document.getElementById('h1').style.display = "block";
}
function showh2() {
    clearTimeout(settime);
    document.getElementById('h2').style.display = "block";
}
```

So the user can only trigger seth1() once.
Than you so much for your help!